# Tmux - disable swap pane using Ctrl-b-o

Tags: shortcuts, tmux

I'm using `Ctrl-b-o` extensively to move focus between panes. However lot of the times I don't release `Ctrl` key and I start swapping panes instead.

Is there a way to turn off this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable, place this in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
unbind-key -T prefix C-o
```

Or maybe you'd like this combination to work like the one you really want to use. If so, then forget about the above, place the following line instead:

```
bind-key -T prefix C-o select-pane -t :.+
```

Restart the tmux server or reload the file (<kbd>prefix</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>`source ~/.tmux.conf`<kbd>Enter</kbd>).